# Some pages on Magento 2 website displaying Error 502 when Varnish cache is enabled - website hosted on Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx VPS

Tags: magento2.3, nginx, varnish, https, ubuntu

I have installed a fresh copy of `Magento 2 (2.3.5 with sample data)` on a VPS which has the following stack: `Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, Mysql, and PHP 7.2 FPM.`

This vanilla installation worked.

However, after enabling Varnish cache on Magento 2, some of the pages on the website are now displaying an Error 502 bad gateway message.

I have tried days troubleshooting this issue, without any luck.
This is a fresh installation of Magneto 2, using the sample data.

I have come across a few posts online which  suggest to increase the `proxy_buffer_size` within the `server block` of the nginx configuration file.  However, this has not worked in my case and I am still receiving a 502 error on some of the links on the Magneto website.

Does anybody know how I could go about resolving this issue and get Varnish working?

I appreciate any help that you could provide. I have provided below the configuration files, logs, and setup information for Nginx, Varnish, and VPS setup.

**Nginx host configuration file:**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server  unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

}


server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;


        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_redirect  http://example.com:8080/  /;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_buffer_size          256k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    }

}


server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example.com/html;
    include /var/www/example.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

**Magento/default vcl config:**

```
root@ubuntu-8gb-nbg1-1:/etc/varnish# cat default.vcl
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
#        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
    .url = "/health_check.php";

        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl = 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

**Error log from /var/log/nginx/error.log:**

```
root@ubuntu-8gb-nbg1-1:/var/log/nginx#
2020/06/18 20:20:03 [error] 20205#20205: *1375 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /men/tops-men/jackets-men.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/what-is-new.html"
```

**Varnish live log:**

`root@ubuntu-8gb-nbg1-1:/var/log/nginx# varnishlog`

- << BeReq    >> 32841

- Begin          bereq 32840 fetch
- Timestamp      Start: 1592504403.501162 0.000000 0.000000
- BereqMethod    GET
- BereqURL       /men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
- BereqHeader    Host: example.com
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
- BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: x.x.x.x
- BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
- BereqHeader    CF-IPCountry: GB
- BereqHeader    CF-RAY: 5a5705a789e73669-MAN
- BereqHeader    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
- BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
- BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
- BereqHeader    accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
- BereqHeader    dnt: 1
- BereqHeader    referer: https://example.com/what-is-new.html
- BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
- BereqHeader    cookie: __cfduid=d6e220d7c9b748b1fc0725cfa4138edce1592497645; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-cache-sessid=true; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; rece
- BereqHeader    CF-Request-ID: 036a41dcb500003669378e9200000001
- BereqHeader    CF-Connecting-IP: x.x.x.x
- BereqHeader    CDN-Loop: cloudflare
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x, 127.0.0.1
- BereqHeader    grace: none
- BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32841
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- BackendOpen    25 boot.default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 48908
- BackendStart   127.0.0.1 8080
- Timestamp      Bereq: 1592504403.501272 0.000110 0.000110
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1592504403.791456 0.290293 0.290183
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
- BerespStatus   502
- BerespReason   Bad Gateway
- BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:20:03 GMT
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- BerespHeader   Content-Length: 182
- BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
- TTL            RFC -1 10 0 1592504404 1592504404 1592504403 0 0
- VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
- TTL            VCL -1 259200 0 1592504404
- TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1592504404
- VCL_return     deliver
- BerespUnset    Content-Length: 182
- BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
- BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
- Storage        malloc Transient
- ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ObjStatus      502
- ObjReason      Bad Gateway
- ObjHeader      Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- ObjHeader      Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:20:03 GMT
- ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
- ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
- Fetch_Body     3 length -
- Gzip           G F E 182 153 80 1144 1154
- BackendReuse   25 boot.default
- Timestamp      BerespBody: 1592504403.791677 0.290515 0.000221
- Length         153
- BereqAcct      1164 0 1164 181 0 181
- End

- << Request  >> 32840

- Begin          req 32839 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1592504403.501053 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1592504403.501053 0.000000 0.000000
- ReqStart       127.0.0.1 49160
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         /men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ReqHeader      Host: example.com
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
- ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: x.x.x.x
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
- ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
- ReqHeader      Connection: close
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
- ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: GB
- ReqHeader      CF-RAY: 5a5705a789e73669-MAN
- ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
- ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
- ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
- ReqHeader      accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
- ReqHeader      dnt: 1
- ReqHeader      referer: https://example.com/what-is-new.html
- ReqHeader      upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
- ReqHeader      cookie: __cfduid=d6e220d7c9b748b1fc0725cfa4138edce1592497645; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-cache-sessid=true; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; rece
- ReqHeader      CF-Request-ID: 036a41dcb500003669378e9200000001
- ReqHeader      CF-Connecting-IP: x.x.x.x
- ReqHeader      CDN-Loop: cloudflare
- ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x, 127.0.0.1
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqHeader      grace: none
- ReqURL         /men/tops-men/jackets-men.html
- ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
- VCL_return     hash
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       MISS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 32841 fetch
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1592504403.791718 0.290665 0.290665
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespStatus     502
- RespReason     Bad Gateway
- RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- RespHeader     Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:20:03 GMT
- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
- RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
- RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32840
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- RespUnset      Age: 0
- RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
- RespHeader     Expires: -1
- RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
- RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- RespUnset      X-Varnish: 32840
- RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1592504403.791760 0.290707 0.000041
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 153
- RespHeader     Connection: close
- Timestamp      Resp: 1592504403.791802 0.290749 0.000042
- ReqAcct        1141 0 1141 286 153 439
- End

- << Session  >> 32839

- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       127.0.0.1 49160 a0 127.0.0.1 6081 1592504403.501004 22
- Link           req 32840 rxreq
- SessClose      REQ_CLOSE 0.291
- End

**netstat output:**

```
root@ubuntu-8gb-nbg1-1:/etc/nginx/sites-available# netstat -plntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19887/varnishd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19887/varnishd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      870/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:2222   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7853/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20204/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20204/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18327/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20204/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::6081                 :::*                    LISTEN      19887/varnishd      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      20204/nginx: master 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           18327/systemd-resol 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> proxy_buffer_size          256k;

That size is huge and won't do you good. You can read the guide on [how to tune it properly](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx) with one important note: `fastcg_buffer_size` and `proxy_buffer_size` are essentially the same thing, they are just applied to different upstream modules of NGINX.

- `proxy_buffer_size` is the buffer for *header* of HTTP response of NGINX's proxy module
- `fastcgi_buffer_size` is the buffer for *header* of HTTP response of NGINX's fastcgi module

Because it is a header, it makes little sense to put things like 256k for that buffer because even a complete page HTML will hardly reach that size.

When you enable Varnish, Magento code will indeed output more HTTP headers, specifically `X-Magento-Tags` may be very large depending on catalog size *and* if looking at a category page.

For this you need to adjust both `proxy_buffer_size` and `fastcgi_buffer_size`.
Why is because in your setup NGINX uses both modules: it *proxies* requests to Varnish (TLS termination), and does FastCGI communication to PHP-FPM.

So aside from tuning `proxy_buffer_size`, you need to do the same for `fastcgi_buffer_size` and tune it up as needed.
You can either do this alongside `fastcgi_` directives in `/var/www/example.com/html/nginx.conf.sample` or add this globally, e.g. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf` and make sure it is loaded from `nginx.conf`.

Don't forget to tune `*_busy_buffers_size` as well as per the guide.
E.g.:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 16k;
```

Comment: Although your answer is right and also tuning you suggest is right it does not resolve the real issue for the big headers which are coming from magento large configurable products. No matter the tuning the issue must be addressed and not only increasing values in nginx and varnish. Do you have any solution to this please?

Comment: @G.G. Why there must be another solution?

Comment: because this is not fixing all issues. check this post please: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350051/extreme-big-headers-only-in-large-configurable-products/350075

Comment: @G.G. The GitHub issue linked on that question states that  it’s fixed in Magento 2.4.1

Comment: Yes....We have already used that patch but again this is not fixing the issue. Is there a way maybe to bypass pages with big headers from varnish?